# Heatmap only displays every other row name

Tags: r, heatmap

I use heatmap.2 in order to show the share of state ownership in African countries over time. However, the heatmap displays **only every second** country name as label. I would like to make sure that every column (country name) appears as a row label on the heatmap. This is the code to reproduce a sample of the dataset:

```
DF <- structure(list(year = 2000:2004, Djibouti = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
    Eritrea = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Ethiopia = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
    Swaziland = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Namibia = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
    `Equatorial Guinea` = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Libya = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), Mozambique = c(1, 
    1, 1, 0.666666666666667, 0.666666666666667), Tunisia = c(1, 
    1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5), Botswana = c(0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 
    0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 0.666666666666667), 
    Gambia = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Angola = c(1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.666666666666667, 
    0.666666666666667), Togo = c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5), Chad = c(0.666666666666667, 
    0.666666666666667, 0.666666666666667, 0.333333333333333, 
    0.333333333333333), Algeria = c(NA, NA, 0, 0.5, 0.333333333333333
    ), Zimbabwe = c(0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 
    0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333), Mali = c(1, 1, 1, 
    0.5, 0.5), Liberia = c(1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.25), Cameroon = c(0.333333333333333, 
    0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 
    0.333333333333333), Kenya = c(0.666666666666667, 0.666666666666667, 
    0.666666666666667, 0.666666666666667, 0.666666666666667), 
    `Central African Republic` = c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.25), 
    Zambia = c(0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 
    0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333), Egypt = c(0.333333333333333, 
    0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 
    0.333333333333333), `Sierra Leone` = c(0.5, 0.333333333333333, 
    0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333), 
    `Congo Brazzaville` = c(0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 
    0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333), 
    Tanzania = c(0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 
    0.4, 0.4), Burundi = c(0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 
    0.333333333333333, 0.25, 0.25), Benin = c(0.333333333333333, 
    0.333333333333333, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25), Nigeria = c(1, 0.333333333333333, 
    0.333333333333333, 0.25, 0.25), `South Africa` = c(0.25, 
    0.25, 0.25, 0, 0), `Congo Kinshasa` = c(0.333333333333333, 
    0.25, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2), Ghana = c(0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 
    0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333), 
    Morocco = c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5), Niger = c(0.5, 0, 0, 
    0, 0), Rwanda = c(0.5, 0.5, 0, 0.5, 0.5), `Guinea-Bissau` = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0), `Burkina Faso` = c(0.5, 0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 
    0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333), Malawi = c(0.333333333333333, 
    0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 
    0.333333333333333), Gabon = c(0, 0, 0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 
    0.333333333333333), Madagascar = c(0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 
    0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 0), Guinea = c(0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0), Lesotho = c(0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0), Mauritania = c(0.5, 
    0, 0, 0, 0), `South Sudan` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), `Ivory Coast` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Senegal = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0), Somalia = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Sudan = c(0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0), Uganda = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 5L
), class = "data.frame")
```

This is the code for the heatmap:

```
rev.heat.colors <- function(n) rev(heat.colors(n))

DF<-DF[, order(colSums(-DF, na.rm=T))]
heatmap.2(as.matrix(t(DF[2:50])),trace = "none",  
          Rowv=NULL, 
          Colv=NULL, dendrogram="none",
          labCol=DF$year,labRow=colnames(DF[c(2:50)]),
          cexRow = 0.7,
          cexCol =  0.7,
          lhei=c(0.25,1), lwid=c(0.25,1), margins=c(3,6),
          colsep=1:16, rowsep=1:50, sepcolor="white",
          col="rev.heat.colors")
```

Even though I specify that all country names (DF[c(2:50]) shall be used as row names, only every second name appears.

I would appreciate any help!

Comment: I believe the label appearance will change based on the plot window size? Do the labels appear as expected with a larger plot window size? Or, try putting the heatmap in a `png` or `jpg` with larger `width` and `height` parameters. It should show all of your labels.

Comment: Thank you! It doesn't work with a larger plot window size or jpeg, but as pdf output!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered using ggplot instead of heatmap.2?
Might be easier to influence the appearance of the output, using `geom_tile`

Here is an example:

```
require(tidyverse)
require(ggplot2)

DF %>% 
  gather(country,value,-year) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = factor(year), y = factor(country, levels = rev(names(DF))), fill = value)) +
  geom_tile(color = "white") +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "yellow", high = "red") +
  labs(x = "year", y = "country")
```

[image: Example plot]

Comment: Thank you for sharing this idea. And I agree - it is much easier to adjust!